# Maximum (micro) SD card speed class for HTC EVO?

Tags: external-sd, performance, htc-evo

What is the maximum class (e.g., 2,4,6,8,10) supported of microSD card supported by the HTC EVO?

I noticed an improvement in performance when upgrading from the Class 2 to a faster card on my Hero.  I don't want to pay extra for performance that won't benefit my EVO.

HTC and Sprint have not included this information in their specs and I can't find it elsewhere.  Either I'm not understading something fundamental about SD classes or it's not published where I'm searching.

Comment: I should add I'm currently using Class 6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like someone [sent HTC an email back in July](http://community.sprint.com/baw/message/197756#197756) and got the following response:

> I understand you want to know which speed is the best for your device as far as SD card is concerned. We have tested the devices on a class 4 speed. I could not recommend anything higher than that. The phone may be capable of running a higher-class speed, but we have only tested it on a class 4.

You may also want to email HTC support and see what they officially say.  From I've been reading, people have been using Class 6 just fine.  Not sure about 8 or 10.