# What is the largest HTC Desire card size?

Tags: htc-desire, ram

Anyone know what the largest size of card the HTC Desire will take? I saw this question,
[Maximum (micro) SD card speed class for HTC EVO?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2096/maximum-micro-sd-card-speed-class-for-htc-evo) Which says a class4, so that's okay as the 32gb card is class 2.

Curious to know how well this will work, as my iPod recently died and I'd like to use my phone as a part time replacement. Anyone experimented with larger cards? I have a 4gb in my phone at the moment and it's okay, I have an 8gb card I'll test when I get home, but would be keen to know results with 16gb and 32gb

Comment: ankajoma: @_HTCdesire_ @davidyell Yes it does. Only 32GB Class 2 
Original Tweet: http://twitter.com/ankajoma/statuses/15722162732142592 

Sent via TweetDeck (www.tweetdeck.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The desire supports sdhc which is upto 32gb so it should work fine. I have a 16gb in my droid and there's no difference noticable from a smaller card (other than it having more capacity).

If you were to find a bigger card (I'm not sure they have any in micro) you'd need a phone that supports SDXC.

Comment: can you provide a reference for your information? I have just got the 64gb SDXC in my desire [cyanogenmod] and it seems to be supported, but slow.