# Largest HTC Desire SD card?

Tags: external-sd

My phone keeps telling me that my storage is low and I barely have any apps on my phone because it tells me this at least three to four times a day. I downloaded this app and moved all my apps (which is a total of three- not including this one) to my SD card and it still keeps telling me that my storage is low. So I deleted some pictures and all my messages. But it keeps telling me the same thing. And I was wondering if I could get a bigger SD card. Mine is a 8 gig. I also was wondering if I can get a new SD card, what is the biggest SD card for my Desire? If I do get a new SD card, can I transfer all my stuff from my old SD card to the new one? Thanks for the help in advance! :)

Comment: I believe the biggest SDHC cards are 32GB, there should be no reason your phone can't use one of those.  Martin's answer is right, though.

Comment: HTC phones tend to be a bit anemic with storage.

Answer (score 9):

Your phone (as most other Android phones) have two kinds of persistent storage -- internal and external. The internal storage is fixed into hardware, and is not intended to be user-serviceable. Your SD card is the external storage, and is very much replaceable -- it is very accessible and can be swapped for another one, including greater capacity ones (see [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3777/largest-htc-desire-card-size) for some additional information).

However, replacing the SD card won't help in your case -- your phone complains that its **internal** storage space is low. This is a problem that has plagued HTC Desire, which is otherwise a great device.

Some things you can do:

- [Move applications to the SD card](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/628/how-can-i-store-android-apps-on-my-sd-card)
- Remove unneeded applications (from your words, not quite possible)
- Clear up some messages, drafts, application caches, and in some cases application data
- Downgrade some of the preinstalled applications that you do not use. See [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5519/htc-desire-low-on-internal-storage-im-clueless/) for more details

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a problem with voiding your warranty and getting your hands a little dirty, I can recommend the use of a custom ROM with support for App2SD(+), D2Ext(+) or D2W.

I'm also a Desire owner, so I really know what you are talking about, this has annoyed me for weeks, until I finally decided to see what all the fuzz with rooting and custom ROMs was about.

So I [rooted my Desire](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1016084) and flashed [this rom](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=957291) in the Data2Whatever-version (D2W), which makes use of a partitioned SD card with an extra partition that, according to my understanding, works as an extension for the internal storage.

So, after all of that, my internal storage capacity has increased to around 240MB instead of ~140MB (yet the effect depends on the size of your SD card (mine is 4GB) and the size of the dedicated sd-ext-partition.)

It may seem tricky (but it isn't really), voids your warranty (which you might need some time), and things like D2W over at XDA-developers is, well, in development, so there might be the occasional bug, but it's been working fine for me for a few weeks now, and as I said, it is really paying off.

So… IF you want to read and test and learn a little, then XDA-developers your way to go.

Comment: Jemus42 what is the best way to do what your talking bout because i own a HTC desire also with a 4 GB SD card in it right now but keeps saying my Internal memory is low and im not sure how i would go about fixing this issue without ruining anything at all...

Answer (score 1):

Turn off your facebook auto updates and auto sync and delete from the phone. Be careful though. Make sure your phone has been synced because all your contact info will be deleted. Recync the phone and reload contact info. This appears to have fixedthe problem on my phone. Also do not use HTC sync to load music as it will fill all available space on the phone. Copy music separately to the micro SD card.